# Getting a 404 error when instantiating a core java class in a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, apache-httpclient-4.x, jira-rest-java-api

I am building a web application in Java and when I am trying to instantiate a core java class from a servlet class and use methods of that class, I am getting a 404 error. I have been trying to figure out the reason for long but couldn't find any.

Code:
Servlet Class:

```
public class SupportPage extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    // When i remove this part, the app runs fine.
    JiraRest jiraRest = new JiraRest();
    String key = null;
    try {
        key = jiraRest.createissue(12403, 10000, "test", "test");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HttpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("Ticket with key: "+key +" created");
    out.println("</html>");
    return;
}}
```

Java Class:

```
public class JiraRest {
public String createissue(Integer projectid, Integer issuetypeid, String summary, String description)
        throws JSONException, IOException, URISyntaxException, HttpException {
    JSONObject fields = new JSONObject();
    fields.put("project", new JSONObject().put("id", projectid.toString()));
    fields.put("issuetype", new JSONObject().put("id", issuetypeid.toString()));
    fields.put("summary", "test");
    fields.put("customfield_10004", "testdvf");
    //fields.put("description", "this is a test.Kindly ignore!");

    JSONObject issue = new JSONObject();
    issue.put("fields", fields);
    System.out.println(issue);

    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(issue.toString());
    se.setContentType("application/json");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://jira.endurance.com/rest/api/latest/issue?os_username=abc&os_password=xyz");
    post.setEntity(se);
    post.addHeader("Accept", "*/*");
    post.addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    String json_string = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    System.out.println(json_string);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json_string);
    return obj.getString("key");

}}
```

The Java Class is making REST calls. 
URL i am trying to access: localhost/ProjectName/support.
When I remove the JiraRest class usage in SupportPage class, it works fine.
Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Adding StackTrace
http://pastebin.com/fdXmghU5

Comment: Any errors in the log?

Comment: yeah, org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpException  and java.lang.IllegalStateException. But couldn't find any reason for these because the app works fine on removing that part.

Comment: You are most probably missing the HttpClient library - it must be in the **servlet container's classpath**, i.e. in `WEB-INF/lib` of your web application, or in `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib` (if you use Tomcat).

Comment: The HttpClient library is there. If that would have been the case, the application should not have worked at all.

Comment: Edit the question and add the stack trace.

Comment: Stacktrace says that the HttpClient library is not there - in the wrong place maybe? What's in your `lib` folder? Or are you using Maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you have packed all required and dependent libraries with your WAR file, or simply copy them under container shared library folder.

You stack says you have missed some library/class, stuffs...

Comment: I copied the jars in the WEB-INF/lib and it worked. Actually i was expecting that it would take the jars from the maven repository but it wasn't. Later, i linked the app to the .m2 of maven and it worked normally.